# What is the correct way to implement multiple models in my situation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a **List** page that contains list of flight info, and a **Create** page that will either create new or edit existing flight info. However, the **Create** page contains more than just the flight info model but 2 other models' info, and that is the reason why I am confused right now.

```
**Models**
Flight
ID  MasterAWB  Airline  ShipmentCount  ...

FlightHouseAWB
ID  FlightID  HouseAWB  CreateTime

Shipment
ID  HouseAWB  Shipper  Receiver  ...
```

This is a sample of how these models are related. FlightHouseAWB is like a middleman between the two models. When I Click on the create/edit button in **List** page, a flight model is passed into **Create**'s view, and that will be used to generate the partial view below.

```
**Create**
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "CharterFlight", FormMethod.Post, new { novalidate = "true", name = "charterFlightForm", id = "charterFlightForm", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { id = "ValidationSummary", @class = "text-danger" })
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Common/ObjectPartialView.cshtml", Model, new ViewDataDictionary { { "colNum", "2" } });

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="Submit" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />&nbsp;
            <input id="Back" type="button" value="Back to List" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Currently my idea is to create a view model that contains all the necessary fields from the 3 models, and when I click on submit on the **Create** page, all filled up data will goes back to the view model correctly. However I am not sure if this setup will work? I mean will this view model updates all three models? I guess I am just really weak at the concept of MVC and needed some guidance.

I hope I have provided enough information for you guys to ask me some questions or give advice. Let me know if I need to give more info, thanks.

Comment: IMHO, If you could have a relational mapping of your Models you can create a matching ViewModel and bind to UI otherwise you need to have a single ViewModel(with all the properties required) and bind to UI but after submitting the data back to controller, it would be your job to populate data from different properties inside POSTed ViewModel into corresponding Models and store to your database.

Comment: I believe these models are relational mapped. So in best case I do no need to update them manually in controller, or i just need to query the right record or create a new one with the info i have from the view model?

Comment: My be the code posted in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880723/asp-net-mvc-5-customer-address-one-to-one-relationship) could help you further to understand the implementation.

Comment: Create view model with your three model classes, not one view model contains all fields.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem in the create page I will need the user to input data both from Flight and Shipment model, but if I implement just the FlightHouseAWB and Shipment model, those filed will not return correctly. Does that mean I need to do both? and insert the data into the model when back into the controller?